# How to add SQL database to screen

Tags: sql, database, lightswitch-2013

I have a SQL database with 2 tables

[image]

When I add a screen, the screen data doesn't show that database name.. how to add that database to the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to import the tables as entities into LightSwitch.

To do so, right click the Server project, select Add Data Source, select Database, then enter the relevant DB details. Once this is done you should have access to the entities and be able to add screens for them.